# The adodb sql connection is giving run time error on certain machines

Tags: vba, adodb

I am using the following connection string to use adodb in vba. I am creating this as a template for my co-workers, but I found it worked on some of the laptops while other laptops give `runtime error -2147467259: method 'Open" of object '_Connection' failed`,

Here is my connection string:

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    conn.Open
```

the `conn.open` is where the error come from, how could I fix this? Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know the versions of Excel your co-workers are using?

Comment: we are using the same version.

Comment: Did you remove UID and passwords from the connection string, or they weren't there to begin with? Or is it integrated security (SSPI)?

Comment: UID and passwords are not required to use this, I assume. So, there weren't UID and pw in the connection string.

Comment: If a VPN is required, do all your coworkers have it running?